# How to do polling in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to fetch the latest data from MySQL using polling but no success. Not even getting any error.

I tried the [example provided by PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml).

```
        <hibernate-version>4.2.4.Final</hibernate-version>
        <primeface-version>5.0</primeface-version>
        <mySQL-version>8.0.16</mySQL-version>
```

**Updated Question:**

```
public class StudentBean {

    List<Student> lstLiveData = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public List<Execution> getLstLiveData() {
        return lstLiveData;
    }

    public void setLstLiveData(List<Student> lstLiveData) {
        this.lstLiveData = lstLiveData;
    }

public void getDataFromDB() {

        List<Object> liveData = executionBo.findLiveDataById(selectedId);
        Iterator<Object> live = liveData.iterator();
        liveData.clear();
        while (live.hasNext()) {
            Object[] obj = (Object[]) live.next();

            Student student = new Student();
            student.setStudentId(Integer.parseInt(obj[0].toString()));  

            lstLiveData.add(student); 
        }
    }

}
```

Student.xhtml

```
<h:form>
   <h:panelGrid >

    <p:poll interval="3" listener="#{StudentBean.getDataFromDB}" update="studentId" />


<p:dataTable id="studentId" var="varTS"
    value="#{StudentBean.lstLiveData}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">

    <f:facet name="header"> Student Id </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{varTS.id}" />
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

</h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```

I expect that every 3 second latest data from db should fetch.

Comment: What is the scope of your bean? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Scope is session

Comment: Your bean does not have a property `liveData`.

Comment: And not a visible name of `StudentBean`

Comment: The updated question, I visibility is there. I just forgot to add that

Comment: Just to update, I tried sample code of polling on login page which does have `<f:view>` and `<h:head>` tag and polling working but another page which has `<ui:composition template="/pages/layout.xhtml">` does not work and `layout.xhtml` has `<h:head>` tag

Comment: **Issue resolved:** Page form element MUST be defined **form id**. if the user does not provide then listener method do not get called but polling will happen. Thanks for helping on this.

Comment: If you've resolved it, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Page form element MUST be defined **form id**. `<h:form id="form1">`

if the user does not provide form id then listener method do not get called but polling will happen.

Thanks for helping on this

Comment: This works if  polling is not in `<ui:composition template="/pages/layout.xhtml">`